# using mouse_over when dragging a movie clip onto another movie clip in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseover

I'm' trying to do the following: I want to drag a mc (mc1) over another mc (mc2), and trigger a timeline navigation when it's over--not when it's releasaed (mouse is up). Apparently flash doesn't recognize the mouse is over mc2 because it's reading it only as being over mc1. This is probably very simple but I'm lost as to how to do it.

Feeble attempt at code:

```
mc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mcOver1);

function mcOver1(Event:MouseEvent):void {
mc2.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

When I'm not dragging anything it works fine, because flash can detect where the mouse is. But I'm unsure how to get flash to detect the mouse's location when it's dragging a movie clip. I tried basing the code on the location of the movie clip I was dragging (mc1) but that didn't work, either.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: ok, I just thought of a really cheap workaround, but I'd still like to know how to do it without needing a workaround. Basically, since my mc (mc1) is so small, I made it so that the mc's x-position is 5 pixels more than the cursor's x-position, so mc2 recognizes the mouse now:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging1, true);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging1, true);

function startDragging1(e:MouseEvent) {
    mc1.startDrag();
    mc1.x = mouseX + 5;
    }
```

Comment: The **mc1** is interactive and intercepts mouse events. Set its properties **mouseEnabled** and **mouseChildren** both to **false** at the moment you start dragging it.

Comment: Thank you! That helps me out.